# String.Format doesn't work as expected

Tags: c#

Maybe its my machine, but this doesn't make any sense.

`String.Format` doesn't work.  These two should technically equal, but do not.  What's missing?  I'm using ASP.NET 3.5 on Windows 7.

```
 string.Format("{0};{1};{2};{3};{4};{5};{7};{8};{9}"
                  , "711.01"
                  , "711.01"
                  , "711.01"
                  , "136.74"
                  , "136.74"
                  , "136.74"
                  , "136.74"
                  , "711.01"
                  , "711.01"
                  , "711.02 br ");

 //and
string.Join(";"
                  , new[]{"711.01"
                  , "711.01"
                  , "711.01"
                  , "136.74"
                  , "136.74"
                  , "136.74"
                  , "136.74"
                  , "711.01"
                  , "711.01"
                  , "711.02"});
```

Comment: You mean aside from the stray "br" in the first one?

Comment: At the very least, show the resulting strings.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are missing `{6}` in the `Format` example.

```
"{0};{1};{2};{3};{4};{5};{7};{8};{9}"
```

should be

```
"{0};{1};{2};{3};{4};{5};{6};{7};{8};{9}"
```

Answer (score 4):

As pointed out by Chris you have an extra br. You're also missing {6} from your string.format:

```
 string.Format("{0};{1};{2};{3};{4};{5};{6};{7};{8};{9}"
                     , "711.01"
                     , "711.01"
                     , "711.01"
                     , "136.74"
                     , "136.74"
                     , "136.74"
                     , "136.74"
                     , "711.01"
                     , "711.01"
                     , "711.02");
```

Comment: It might be worth pointing out if you had [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) it would have dimmed the 6th variable showing you that you weren't referencing it anywhere in your code. Everyone ♥'s ReSharper.